# Problem with Windows 10 Toast Notifications in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, toast, visual-studio-2019

I´m having a problem with the ToastNotifications system in Visual Studio 2019 with a C# app.

The problem is that I´m using the package NotificationsExtensions.Toasts installed via NuGet for creating my own Windows 10 notifications, but when I try to create an object of ToastNotification class it doesn´t seem to be imported with the rest of package as can be seen in the image:

[image: ToastNotification problem]

I have also searched on the Internet and seen that it could be resolved by adding Windows.UI as a reference to the the project, but when I try to add this reference I get that Windows tab in the references manager is empty although the Windows 10 SDK is installed and the target platform is indicated.

[image: Empty Windows references tab]

[image: Target platform of the project]

Comment: Given the other Toast classes seem available, are you sure its not called something else? or in a different using?

Comment: The class, in theory, is called like this in both Toast Notifications Github (https://github.com/WindowsNotifications/NotificationsExtensions/wiki/Toast-Notifications) and Microsoft Documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification)

Comment: ToastNotification is a WinRT class. Your app is definitely a UWP app and not a Windows Desktop app?

Comment: My app is a Windows Service, could this be the problem?